# Trying to send email automatically of a Google Docs created through apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-docs, email-attachments

Using script I replaced body txt in a copied doc. I want to get that doc id and send that via email automatically after doc was created. Not sure if its possible but my current code is below. Please help.

```
var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1baIoahNT9YJ84mnUcp1pyWR0U5v235z29vPCkiv4rIc");
var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1mmFKjNnbTy2k8ZWobtcvdtIcwyse3NVd");
var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(deptName + " " + "Cost Recovery Agreement", templateResponseFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
var body = doc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{{DeptName}}", deptName);
body.replaceText("{{DeptCo}}", deptCo);
body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}", firstName);
body.replaceText("{{LastName}}", lastName);
doc.saveAndClose();
var id = doc.getId();
var subject = "Welcome to ResponseMaster!";
var message = title + " " + lastName + "," + "\n\n" + "Thank you for choosing ResponseMaster as your dedicated software for your fire department.";
var costRecoveryForm = DriveApp.getFileById();
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message, { attachments: [costRecoveryForm] });
```

I am already have the e.values set up properly further above the script but this is all the script that deals with the issue.

Comment: `var id = copy.getId();`

Answer (score 0):

By putting the Google Doc URL in the email body, Gmail will show it as an attachment (if the recipient has access to the file).

Like in the following image.
[image: Attaching a Google Drive file by adding the URL to the mail body]

**So here is my approach:**

```
let templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1hNJ8SUybJn8nnJg87Pm22dzI0_3L0N17ZbYhV1HeUrM");
let templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Xzs1k-e8q2NYCTHg-4yit7zFWTF7L33h");
let copy = templateFile.makeCopy(`${deptName} Cost Recovery Agreement`, templateResponseFolder);
let copyId = copy.getId();

// Here I give the user permission to view the file I'm sending him
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).addViewer(userEmail); 

let doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
let copyUrl = doc.getUrl();
let body = doc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{{DeptName}}", deptName);
body.replaceText("{{DeptCo}}", deptCo);
body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}", firstName);
body.replaceText("{{LastName}}", lastName);
doc.saveAndClose();

let subject = "Welcome to ResponseMaster!";
let message = `${title} ${lastName},\n\nThank you for choosing ResponseMaster as your dedicated software for your fire department.\n\n${copyUrl}`;
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message);
```